# How old is the Dude?

Tags: character, the-big-lebowski

Is there any reference as to how old the Dude is in *The Big Lebowski*? Looks 45ish but I was wondering if there is any reference to it in the movie.

Comment: They claim he's 47 [here](http://thebiglebowski.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dude), but that's just because they're using Jeff Bridges' birthday without explaining why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The character of Jeff Lebowski is said to be based on Jeff Dowd who was a member of the anti-war radical group the Seattle Liberation Front.

Dowd was born November 20, 1949.

At the beginning of the movie you can see the speech of George Bush "This will not stand, this aggression against Kuwait." which was on Aug. 5, 1990.

So I would say he was 40.

Comment: however, the date was 9/11/91, which can be seen when he writes a check for a quart of milk right after that George Bush scene was shown

Comment: @amphibient good catch on the date, but it was a quart of half & half for his white russians :)

Comment: I guess he had to postdate his check because he was broke - again ;)

Comment: you're right, i can't believe i missed that...

Answer (score 3):

If what he says about helping to write the Port Huron Statement is true, he would have had to have been college age in 1962 when it was written.  So I'm thinking he was at least 47 when the movie took place in '91.